# Change width of column exsis in dataset bind to grid view ? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i am trying to increase width of column that i created in c# my code is ,

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Project ID", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Title", typeof(string)));
     dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(double)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("email", typeof(double)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("description", typeof(double)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ownerdetail", typeof(double)));
    DataRow dr;
```

how to set its width ??

i have found to implement it like,

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Title", typeof(string))).width;
```

but ".with" does not exsis then how would we solve it ?

hopes for your suggestion thanks in advance

best regards

EDITED:

How to set Column exsis in grid view my code is ,

```
GridViewHcost.DataSource = dset;
```

i try it as help from net ,

```
GridViewHcost.Columns.width=20;
```

but in this command ".Width" does not exsis

i also try ,

```
GridViewHcost.Columns[2].ControlStyle.Width = 200;
```

result in error column not exsis may it is considering gridview column like databound etc

Hopes for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase the colums of a DataTAble... This contains data. It does not display anything... If you want to display data, use a gridView and ibnd your data on it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a msdn link for the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178296%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

**Make sure that you have all ready bind data to your gridview**

### Edit 1

Set the [DataGridViewColumn.Width Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width.aspx).

You can do this either in the Visual Studio Designer or through code:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
column.Width = 60;
```

You should be aware that the [DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode.aspx) setting can affect a column's width too.

Comment: is it possible for particular column  with of datagrid?

Comment: See all these grids are inherited from the same control. And they have tabular structure so I think it will be there also.

Comment: when i tried "GridViewHcost.Columns[1].ItemStyle.Width = 150;" after attaching dataset to it it give me error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: i think the the command above i mention is looking for filds of column like bound button etc that why it is giving error ?

Comment: first bind the grid then set the width.

Comment: GridViewHcost.DataSource = dset;
        GridViewHcost.DataBind();                                               GridViewHcost.Columns[1].ItemStyle.Width = 150;

Comment: andset have value i have checked still then it is giving error i mentioned you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the width of a certain `Gridview` column (bound to a `Datatable`) with the `RowDataBound` event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes["width"] = "200px";
}
```